# Kafka Connect Reread Entire File for KSQLDB Debugging or KSQLDB possiblity to insert all events after query creation?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I start to develop with KSQLDB and alongside with Kafka-connect. Kafka-connect is awesome and everything is well and has the behaviour to not reread the records if it detects that it was already read in the past (extrem useful for production). But, for development and debugging of KSQLDB queries it is necessary to replay the data, as ksqldb will create table entries on the fly on emitted changes. If nothing is replayed the to 'test' query stays empty. Any advice how to replay a csv file with kafka connect after the file is inserted for the first time? Maybe, ksqldb has the possiblity to reread the whole topic after the table is created. Has someone the answer for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the source connector with a different name, or give the CSV file a new name. Both should cause it to be re-read.

Comment: That solved my issue, ty. But, only the renaming of the name attribute of the kafka connect tasks will trigger a reinsert. renaming the files end in nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had also a problem in my configuration file and ksqldb did not recognize the

```
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
```

option. Use the above command, notice the ', to force ksqldb to reread the whole topic from the beginning after a table/stream creation command. You have to set it manually every time you connect via ksql-cli or client.